# Jquery show/hide not working until refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a checkout page that has three fieldsets:
fieldset id="1", fieldset id="2", fieldset id="3".  When the page loads, I need it to hide fieldsets 2 and 3 and only show fieldset 1.  This is what my jquery looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#1").show();                          
  $("#2").hide();
  $("#3").hide();
  $("#4").hide();
});
```

When I load the page I can see fieldset 1 and fieldset 2.  If I refresh the page, it looks perfect, but upon first load, it's weird.  Any suggestions?

Comment: a link please :), and can you add it to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5):

First thing you need to do is properly name your ID's.  ID's can't start with a number.

If you change the name to `set_1` you can do the initial hide with CSS.

```
#set_2, #set_3, #set_4 { display:none; }
```

No JS needed.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding other issues, your IDs are invalid, which will always cause unpredictable results.  Ids MUST begin with a letter.

Beyond that, it is difficult to answer your question without further insight into the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#el_1").show();
  $("#el_2, #el_3, #el_4").hide(); 
});
```

Should all be valid jQuery, assuming that there is no ID collision (you can only use an ID once per page).